# How can I know if RoomDatabase.clearAllTables() has finished?

Tags: android, android-room

[`RoomDatabase#clearAllTables()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#clearAllTables()) returns `Unit`. So, how can one know when it has finished? Is that possible at all?

Update: That is the generated code taken from `AppDatabase_Impl.java`

```
  @Override
  public void clearAllTables() {
    super.assertNotMainThread();
    final SupportSQLiteDatabase _db = super.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    boolean _supportsDeferForeignKeys = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
    try {
      if (!_supportsDeferForeignKeys) {
        _db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = FALSE");
      }
      super.beginTransaction();
      if (_supportsDeferForeignKeys) {
        _db.execSQL("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = TRUE");
      }
      _db.execSQL("DELETE FROM `something`");
      _db.execSQL("DELETE FROM `something2`");
      super.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      super.endTransaction();
      if (!_supportsDeferForeignKeys) {
        _db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = TRUE");
      }
      _db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(FULL)").close();
      if (!_db.inTransaction()) {
        _db.execSQL("VACUUM");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would expect that to be synchronous -- it is done when the function returns. You might peek at the generated code to confirm this.

Comment: I've read somewhere else that it spawns a new thread (without any proof). I don't know how to navigate to the code as the builder returns an interface, so following the code in Android Studio only leads me to the abstract method. Any hint on this?

Comment: You will find generated code from all sources in a subdirectory of your `build/` directory for your module.

Comment: good idea :-) found the code, added it above. Guess it is really synchronous - can you confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated code for `clearAllTables()` is synchronous. You can see from the generated code in your question that the function implements the database transaction and deletes the contents of the tables directly within that function. All of the functions called on `_db`, such as `execSQL()`, are synchronous.